# Getting specific user info on button click

Tags: java, rest, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I have this dummy app where i've got a Recycler view which I populated with Data from my server. Every user has an Id, Picture and Name.

The profile pictures you see here are image buttons, When clicked I want to display a profile page with the specific data of the clicked user.

[image]

How do i tell the app that it should display the profile of the specific User that has been clicked? I just need the idea in words if possible you can use a dummy code example.

Comment: If you understand Kotlin, I think this [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FireApp/tree/master/app/src/main/java/ro/alexmamo/firebase/main/profile/movies) will help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to [check this tutorial](https://antonioleiva.com/recyclerview-listener/) here for better understanding on how you can achieve the behavior that you want.

In case of handling the `onClickListener` from your activity you need to work based on a callback implementation with an interface. Pass the interface from the activity to your adapter and then call the callback function from your adapter when some items are clicked.

Here's a sample implementation from the tutorial.

Let us first have the interface.

```
  public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(ContentItem item);
}
```

You need to modify your adapter to take the listener as the parameter like the one stated below.

```
private final List<ContentItem> items;
private final OnItemClickListener listener;

public ContentAdapter(List<ContentItem> items, OnItemClickListener listener) {
    this.items = items;
    this.listener = listener;
}
```

Now in your `onBindViewHolder` method, set the click listener.

```
@Override public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bind(items.get(position), listener);
}

public void bind(final ContentItem item, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
    ...
    itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override public void onClick(View v) {
            listener.onItemClick(item);
        }
    });
}
```

Now Setting the Adapter in Your `RecylerView`

```
recycler.setAdapter(new ContentAdapter(items, new ContentAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override public void onItemClick(ContentItem item) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Item Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}));
```

Here you get the Adapater Code like this:

```
public class ContentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContentAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(ContentItem item);
    }

    private final List<ContentItem> items;
    private final OnItemClickListener listener;

    public ContentAdapter(List<ContentItem> items, OnItemClickListener listener) {
        this.items = items;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bind(items.get(position), listener);
    }

    @Override public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView name;
        private ImageView image;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        }

        public void bind(final ContentItem item, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
            name.setText(item.name);
            Picasso.with(itemView.getContext()).load(item.imageUrl).into(image);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                    listener.onItemClick(item);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```